# Implementing Ajax in php MVC

Tags: php, jquery, templates

Im want to implement Ajax in php mvc project, i want to add a user into the database using ajax.
i tried to follow a youtube tutorial but couldn't insert the data, here is my index.html page:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <!-- Required meta tags -->
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="name">Name:</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
       </div>
       <button type="submit" onclick="saveData()">Add</button>
      </form>
     </div>

     <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="views/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="views/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
     function saveData(){
      var name=$('#name').val();
      var email=$('#email').val();
      $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "?controller=pages&action=add",
       data: "name="+name+"&email"+email,
       success:function(msg){
       alert('Success,ajotuer fil base');
     }
    });
    }
  </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

and here is my controller funciton :

```
public function add(){
  if (isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['email'])){
    echo 'error couldnt retreive inputs';
  }
  else {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    User::save($name,$email);
  }
}
```

the user.php file

```
public static  function save($name,$email){
  $db = Db::getInstance();
  $req = $db->prepare("INSERT into user(id,name,email) VALUES ('',?,?)");
  $req->bindParam(1,$name);
  $req->bindParam(2,$email);
  $req->execute();
}
```

UPDATE 1:Added full index.html file

Comment: syntax error in your php...can clearly see it in syntax highlighter within the question code. Also path to php file not used in $ajax url

Comment: by using ?controller=pages&action=add that way the routes.php file will send the request to the file page_controller which will handle the request.
For the php error syntax its the ' couldn't ' word i removed it but still could insert data

Comment: but you said it is an html page. Not clear how your mvc works or what framework you are using or how the server side routing works

Comment: for the mvc ,im following this tutorial [link](http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/)

Comment: Hey, @KaisBettaieb. First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please tell us what exactly is going wrong? Are you getting any error in your browser's console? Perhaps it's a good idea referring to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask.

Comment: @GustavoStraube thank you for your answer,i just found the problem , it was in the url attribute syntax i was missing a '&' in the end after '?controller=pages&action=add'

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems at first glance:

First, in your JS code, you've misspelled `function`:

```
success:fucntion(msg){  // <-- fuCNtion should be fuNCtion
  alert('Success,ajotuer fil base');
}
```

Second, in your PHP code, you haven't escaped the quotation mark in your string. If you use a single quotation mark in your string, either use double quotes around the string or escape the single quotation mark:

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) || isset($_POST['email'])){
  echo 'error couldn\'t retrieve inputs'; // or:
  echo "error couldn't retrieve inputs";
}
```

Try that and let us know if that works.

Comment: you still misspelled `"function"`

Comment: still the same problem.

Comment: @KaisBettaieb OK, are you getting any errors at all? If you open the developer console in your browser, do you get any Javascript warnings/errors when you click the submit button? Have you verified that the controller action is actually executed? Is the `save()` method of your `User` model working properly if you call it manually with a fixed username and email address?

Comment: @rickdenhaan i get this error "missing } after property list " i looked for it in google ,what i found is that im forgetting a comma in index.html but i don't know where, and "Invalid JSON!JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data  get_scripts.js.php:16151 "

Comment: @rickdenhaan i tried executing the save() method of my user class with fixed proprieties and it worked

Comment: OK that javascript error doesn't seem to come from the code snippets you posted in the original question. This answer obviously didn't fix the problem, so instead of continuing the discussion here, can you update your question with more code from your index.html?